# What is the best tag to store links in at the Web.Config file?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, web-config

I may put the website on a different server and it has links linking it especially as it is on sharepoint so there are addresses and ports, so i thought it's better to save the link in Web.Config file in order not to need to change it a lot. So where is the best place or tag to put it in, like for example connection strings is at: configuration->connectionstrings.

Comment: Since u are using SharePoint have u looked at http://www.codeplex.com/SPConfigStore. May not be what you are looking for but...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have sometimes used `appSettings` to store link templates

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="link.template1" value="http://example.com:1234/" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Note that the url needs to be xml encoded, so if it includes querystring parameters you will need to encode the `&` characters to `&amp;` (and possibly encode other characters as well):

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="link.template1" value="http://example.com/p1=value&amp;p2=othervalue" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

...and of course I should have hinted on how to use the values. Thanks @[Tchami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/74183/tchami) for providing that answer in the comments; added here for answer completeness:

```
string urlTemplate = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["link.template1"];
```

If you don't already have it, you will need to add a reference to `System.Configuration` to your project, and also a `using System.Configuration` statement in the beginning of the code file.

Comment: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"]

Comment: Thanks @Tchami. I sometimes wish that there was a mechanism for sharing rep points.

Comment: I tried to access it but it didn't read it although the connection strings are read. I even got the Count for the property but it's = ZERO!!

Comment: @Ahmad: verify that you use the correct key, and that the web.config file is deployed properly (so that you are not using a previous version of it for instance).

Comment: WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["link.template1] also works

Comment: this is the code that i have:
<appSettings>
    <add key="k" value="v"/>
  </appSettings>

and

b.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Count;

the output is 0

Comment: @Ahmad: and the <appSettings> element is a located directly in the <configuration> element? If I try this config file, I get `Count = 1`: `<configuration>  <appSettings>  <add key="k" value="v"/>  </appSettings> </configuration>`

Comment: Thanks man. I am sorry it was a stupid mistake of me. Now it works pretty well. You rock ;)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [AppSettings section](http://www.odetocode.com/Articles/345.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I think you best bet here is to use a properties class that stores changes in the web.config.  It's basically the same thing as using  but it allows you to use either a default value set when you initially created the setting, or you can override it and use a value specified from the web.config file.  If you're using VS2005 or VS2008, this is the way to go.
Here's Microsoft's usage page on it: [MSDN: Using Settings in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(VS.80).aspx)